# Issue with the origin of a relationship

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I got two types of relationships between two classes. In one of them, I need to establish the `origin`, however I don't know how. Anyone idea?

```
class A
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  ...
  has_many :out, :method1, model_class: B
  has_many :out, :method2, model_class: B
  ...
end

class B
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  ...
  has_one :in, :something, model_class: A, origin: ?????
  ...
end
```

**Graph**

The type of the relationship is the default one ("#"+ name of the method).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3MtC0k3.png]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the documentation on declaring origins](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships#declaring-origin) I think the issue you're having is that you haven't declared a [second parameter that sets the method](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships#second-parameter-is-a-symbol-that-sets-the-method-and-defaults-relationship-type-and-expected-object-class).

So in your class `A`, you might want to do this:

```
has_many :out, :somethingHere :type1, model_class: B
```

Then in `B`, you might want to do this:

```
has_one :in, :something, model_class: A, :origin: :somethingHere
```

I can't tell you what `somethingHere` should be because you haven't provided enough information about what `A` and `B` are to tell what their association would mean.

Comment: This is the answer. The `origin` options makes the association look for another association of the same name on the corresponding model. You'd use `has_one :in, :something, model_class: A, origin: :method1` and then `B.first.something` would use `#method1` as its relationship type.

Comment: The thing is if you put `origin: :method1`, everyone B with the incoming `#method2` relationship will return `nil`. Do you feel me?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own method. It's something like:

```
class A
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  ...
  has_many :out, :method1, model_class: B
  has_many :out, :method2, model_class: B
  ...
end

class B
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  ...
  # I removed has_one line and include:
  def something
    rel = rels(dir: :incoming).first
    return nil if rel.nil?
    rel.start_node
  end
  ...
end
```

Is it a good solution? Comments please.

Comment: If it works, it works. Not going to argue against it, but it does seem odd for you to define a custom method like this when the framework provides hooks to define such methods for you.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why this is necessary. See my comment on FrobberOfBits's answer. You can email me if you need extra help, I'm one of the maintainers of the Neo4j gem.